# Approximate counts of large numbers

Tags: probability

There is a counter that counts some events and has some threshold T. After reaching the threshold the counter is nullified and a new iteration starts over. The task is to come up with a probability counter that counts every event with some probability p (so as to not count every other event but only some events thus reducing the number of iterations (if I get the problem right)). Find the threshold for a probability counter, at which the actual number of event counts does not exceed T with a probability of 99%.

My thoughts are: imagine that threshold T equals 100. We can select a p value and find an expectation. For example with p equals 0.5 the expectation will be 50 counts. Is the next step to find confidence intervals? In this case how to find variance? 
Or is it a completely different problem? As you can see I cannot even come up with a meaningful title.
EDIT. I changed the title according to the article bellow.

Comment: Can you please upload the question itself? I don't think I understand what you are trying to say...

Comment: That's the problem. I translated the question to English as best as I could but even in language in which the question was originally stated it was hard for me to get the idea in full. I had hoped somebody would see some pattern in some similar problems.

Comment: If I think you are saying what you are saying, I think you are on the right track. Let the original counter be $C$. Assume the probability to be $p$ with which the event is counted. Then you need to find a new threshold for the probability counter $E$, say $T_2$ , such that the $E$ hits $T_2$ before $C$ hits $T$ 99% of the time

Comment: We are probably dealing with Bernoulli distribution. From that we have mean p and standard deviation sqrt(pq). Also we know that z value for 99% CI is 2.576. That's all I could come up with so far.

Comment: Might be it:
http://www.inf.ed.ac.uk/teaching/courses/exc/reading/morris.pdf